# Is it OK to calculate correlation between $x$ and $\frac{y}{x}$?

Tags: correlation, modeling

I have a set of data that looks at individual decisions on an application, and whether or not that particular decision was flagged or not, aggregated by week.  My three variables are `week`, `decisions`, `flags`.

My theory is that the more decisions there are, the higher the relative percentage of flagged decisions.

It's obvious that when I have a higher volume of decisions, I will have a higher volume of flags.  So I've created a variable called `flags per decision` to help judge if the frequency of `flag` increases as `decisions` increase.

When I plot `flags per decision` against the number of `decisions` in that week, I see a moderate linear relationship.

I'm wondering if it's correct to deduce a correlation based on the new measure `flags per decision` and the number of `decisions`.  Can I still use simple statistical functions such as Pearson's $r$ to calculate the correlation?  Are there any caveats I need to watch out for when working in this way?

Comment: Essentially you are fine. You should just watch out for the fact that `flags per decision` is between zero and one; for example, a simple regression model for `flags per decision` might not be a good idea. I also edited your title trying to better reflect the actual problem; feel free to undo the edit if you dislike it.

Comment: If you asssume a linear relationship between $\frac{y}{x}$ and $x$ then you are assuming that there is a quadratic relationship between $y$ and $x$. Indeed, if $\frac{y}{x}=\beta_0 + \beta_1 x$ then $y=\beta_0 x + \beta_1 x^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered in comments, summarized/copied below:

Essentially you are fine.  You should just watch out for the fact that `flags per decision` is between zero and one; for example, a simple regression model for `flags per decision` might not be a good idea.

Also note that assuming a linear relationship between $y/x$ and $x$ then you are assuming a quadratic relationship between $y$ and $x$. Doing the algebra:
$$
   \frac{y}{x} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x + \epsilon
$$
then multiplying through by $x$:
$$
   y = \beta_0 x + \beta_1 x^2 + \epsilon \cdot x
$$
where I have added an error term $\epsilon$ (which with data needs an index $i$).  So, if you think of fitting a model, then you should think about if the variance of the error term is constant for modelling $y$ or for modelling $y/x$.

And, YES, you should **always plot your data**.